# How to include other columns with TOP in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that returns 500,000 rows.  Really slow to return that many records.  I like to use TOP and return a certain amount of rows, but return specific columns as well, like:

```
Select Top 1000, col1, col2, col3 from table
```

Can I do something like this?  If I can't use TOP, then how to return only 1000 rows, but include specific columns?

Comment: You might keep you table as small as possible. using `where`

Comment: Have you tried your query?  It won't work because of an extra comma.  But this will: `Select Top 1000 col1, col2, col3 from table`

Comment: Are you familiar with where clauses?  That's another way to get fewer rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but you have to remove the coma after the number of rows you want to return:

```
Select Top 1000 col1, col2, col3 from table
```

Comment: We typically don't answer a question if only to correct a small typo.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I removed the comma.  Also, I found the LIMIT works too.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok, did not know about this... why not?

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland Because a simple typo question will likely not be very helpful to anyone.  Check for this option under the close menu.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well I would argue it's helpful to the person who asks. Even if it's a simple mistake, isn't it the purpose of Stack Overflow to help others?

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland Stack Overflow isn't successful because it has a database full of questions only helpful to one person.  It works because the questions help _all_ engineers.  You may draw downvotes in the future for answering typo questions (it happened to me...so I stopped doing it).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I totally agree with you that good questions which help all engineers are more important. Still I don't see why we should not answer simple / silly questions. The person will get its answer and as you said, ultimately the up / down votes will do their job to filter out what matters... everyones' happy :)